# get the substrings between {} in a string Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala, substring

I have a string `str=" {$a}/{$b}/{$c}/{$d}"`

I want a function that returns list of strings which are in between `{` and `}`

so for `fun(str)` output should be `List($a,$b,$c,$d)`

I tried 
 `println("""\}.*\{""".r.split("{$a}/{$b}/{$c}/{$d}").toList)`

but I got only `List( {$a,$d})`

Comment: What should it return in case you have `"{{a}}"` or `"{{a}"`?

Comment: Why not split it by "/" and then match the braces?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet both should be List(a)

Comment: @insan-e  i want output for ${{$a}_{$b}} -> List($a,$b) also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use **Scala** **regex** **group capture** for this, like:

```
"""\{(.*?)\}""".r.findAllIn("{$a}/{$b}/{$c}/{$d}").matchData.map(_.group(1)).toList
```

Explanation:

1. `?`: for **non-greedy** capture
2. `findAllIn`: find all **group** pattern
3. `_.group(1)` for **capture** data